# PHP Crop png is not working

Tags: php

not work?

$image = imagecreatefrompng("$filename");

My php code for crop photo

```
$filename="yaaa.png";
$width: 10px;
$height: 10px;
$image = imagecreatefrompng("$filename");
$thumb_width = $width;
$thumb_height = $height;
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;
if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
   $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, 
                   0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, 
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagepng($thumb, $filename, 100);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

im run this code but not working, my pict is dark and text "picture not valid"

why?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `$width` and `$height` is invalid. Change it like this:

```
$width = 10;
$height = 10;
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (with my modifications), I tested it before posting.